# Show only five first lines from text file

Tags: php, while-loop, substr

I have this code (from SteAp):

```
<?php    
$file = fopen("news/news_2013.txt", "r");

$i = 0;
while (!feof($file)) {
    $posts[] = fgets($file);
}
fclose($file);

foreach ($posts as $rawPost ){

    $datePart = substr( $rawPost, 0, 19 );
    $newsPart = substr( $rawPost, 20, 10000 );

    echo $datePart . ': ' . $newsPart . '<br />';
}
?>
```

I use it here: http://flamencopeko.net/news. Works perfect.

I'm trying to make a version for the main page that shows only the five newst lines. Like this: http://flamencopeko.net/index2.php But only with the top five posts. So while (!feof($file)) will not work for this purpose.

Suggestions?

Comment: stop using flat files when you should be using a data base

Comment: in additions your using 2 loops, you could do it in just one, no need to create the $posts array

Comment: Dagon: I actually need two loops to add the colon.

Comment: no you could do that in the one as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a counter and break out of the loop

```
$i = 0;
while (!feof($file)) {
    $posts[] = fgets($file);
    $i++;
    if ($i >= 5) break;
}
```

Comment: Yeah! Wow. Hah. Thanks Musa.